# SSIS licensing when deployed on different machine than SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have data warehouse database on `SQL Server Enterprise`. Currently the SSIS that feeds the data warehouse is running on the same server.

I would like to move the SSIS execution on another server. What are the licensing options for SQL Server for running the SSIS? Can I use SQL Server Standard with server + 1 CAL license? SSIS runs under one service account.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Answer (score 0):

From memory if the two instances are on a separate physical host then two licenses are required. If they are two VM's on the same host then only 1 enterprise license is required for the physical box.

Best to contact your Microsoft Rep or use the Microsoft License Audit Tool (Can't find it right now) for a definitive answer though as these things change over time.

Note: This answer applies to on-premise only, cloud etc. are special cases.